# Metacryptic ep. 2

Tags: cryptic-clues

Solve the 4 cryptic clues below to reveal the final clue. Then, solve that one.

1. Fit, headless rich folk seek Henry's crown (7)
2. ... shapely being? (8)
3. Park authorities hate pirates with furies (6)
4. Brokers are ladies' dates wearing the first hat (6)

(5)

Comment: Where's the ***meta-meta version***, wherein you have four sets of these, solve them to create four more which, when solved, yields one more?!

Comment: coming soon™ ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Number 2:

> ELLIPSIS (def: ..., shapley = ellips(e), + being = is)

Meta:

> HEALTHY ELLIPSIS ANGERS AGENTS (<s>6</s> 5) - *credit @Sid for 1, @randal'thor for 3 and 4*

Answer:

> SPIES (5) - 'Healthy ellipsis' -> 'ellipsis' minus 'ill' -> EPSIS, 'angers' -> anagram,  'agents' -> definition -> SPIES

Answer (score 8):

3. Park authorities hate pirates with furies (6)

   > ANGERS ("park authorities" = rangers, remove (hate) the R or arrrr from pirates, and "furies" as definition)
4. Brokers are ladies' dates wearing the first hat (6)

   > AGENTS ("brokers" as definition, "ladies' dates" = gents, and somehow "the first hat" gives A instead of H?)

Metacryptic (using [Sid's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47632/5373) for clue 1 and [Arth's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47640/5373) for clue 2):

> **Healthy ellipsis angers agents (6)** - solution TBD ...

Comment: I had also thought along these lines, maybe something to do with Arrrr? (But the fury could also be rage and we'd need to make the authorities that hate pirates GA to get GARAGE somehow. And shouldn't the answer be RANGERS, plural?)

Comment: I second M Oehm's thoughts. Since it is authorities, shouldn't it be plural?

Comment: Numbers referring to letters' positions in the alphabet seems to be an American thing; Dan Russell uses it often in his cryptics.

Comment: @MOehm RANGER and ANGER fits so well that I think it must be right, despite the plural issue.

Comment: I have a feeling it could be "Guides". I am not quite clear how to get it, though..

Comment: Clarified. My mistake.

Answer (score 7):

1.Fit, headless rich folk seek Henry's crown (7)

> **HEALTHY** (fit-def. Rich-Wealthy. Without W.(Headless). Henry's Crown= H)

2.... shapely being? (8)

> Possibly **ELLIPSIS**? (Ellips (Shape) +is(Being)) (As mentioned by Arth)

3.Park authorities hate pirates with furies

> **ANGERS** (Park Authorities=Rangers. Without R from Pirates. Def-Furies)

4.Brokers are ladies' dates wearing the first hat

> **AGENTS** (Brokers-Def. Ladies dates-Gents. First Hat=A) (Thanks @Will!)

So, the final metacryptic clue:

> HEALTHY ELLIPSIS ANGERS AGENTS. (6)

Comment: Number 2 is incorrect

Comment: @Matt *Number 2 is unmutual!* (if you don't get the reference, never mind)